# Условие для последнего элемента twig

Tags: php, twig

Помогите составить условие на twig, оно нужно для вывода последней хлебной крошки не в виде ссылки, а в виде просто текста. Есть аналогичное условие на php

```
<?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $i=> $breadcrumb) { ?>
<?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><?php if($i+1<count($breadcrumbs)) { ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a> <?php } else { ?><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?><?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for key, breadcrumb in breadcrumbs %}
    <li>{% if loop.last %}<a href="{{ breadcrumb.href }}">{% endif %}{{ breadcrumb.text }}{% if loop.last %}</a>{% endif %}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ был найден

```
{% for key, breadcrumb in breadcrumbs %}
{% if key + 1 < breadcrumbs|length %}
    <li><a href="{{ breadcrumb.href }}">{{ breadcrumb.text }}</a></li>
{% else %}
    <li>{{ breadcrumb.text }}</li>
{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  {% for key, breadcrumb in breadcrumbs %}
    {% if loop.last %}
      <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">{{ breadcrumb.text }}</li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ breadcrumb.href }}">{{ breadcrumb.text }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляйте небольше поясненение к коду.